# Sticky session enabling in nest js

Tags: nestjs, sticky-session

const httpServer = http.createServer();

// setup sticky sessions
setupMaster(httpServer, {
loadBalancingMethod: "least-connection",
});

How to enable sticky sessions ,similar to node in nest js .

Nest js is framework is it possible to enable sticky session for clustering.

Comment: nest js enable sticky session , for sticky session need httpserver refrence and have to run nest js  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SocketAdapter(app));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sticky-session` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sticky-session) for this purpose.

```js
// Replace 'httpServer' with the server instance you want to use (e.g., Express)
sticky.listen(httpServer, 3000, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```